# How to make s3 bucket use server side encryption with PHP

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

For the current setup I have

Dockered:

- Apache2 server running yii2
- Localstack from aws

I have the current upload file working with no issue.
I am trying to specify encryption for some of the files through this:

```
$key = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));
$s3FileOptions = array_merge($s3FileOptions, [
    'SSECustomerAlgorithm' => 'AES256',
    'SSECustomerKey' => $key,
    'SSECustomerKeyMD5' => base64_encode(md5($key, true)),
]);
```

My file does indeed get saved on the s3 bucket with no issue. However if I download the file from a generated url or using `aws s3 cp`. My file is still unencrypted.

How can I force s3 to use the parameters I am using for encryption in the `putObject`

Comment: I had the exact same issue and had to revert to server side AES encryption (which is reinventing the wheel)... I hope you'll get it solved. If you do, please share the solution. There are too many posts out there that only say. I've fixed it but don't say how then did it.